# Как получить id текущего элемента в owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

```
<div class="owl-carousel carousel-pop-goods">                   
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/4.png" alt="iphone"><h6><a href="#">Iphone 4</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/7.png" alt="iphone"><h6><a href="#">Iphone 7</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/5.jpg" alt="iphone"><h6><a href="#">Iphone 5</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/3.jpg" alt="iphone"><h6><a href="#">Iphone 3</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/5c.jpeg" alt="iphone"><h6><a href="#">Iphone 5c</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/6.jpg" alt="iphone"><h6><a href="#">Iphone 6</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/s6.png" alt="Galaxy S6"><h6><a href="#">Galaxy S6</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/s7.jpg" alt="Galaxy S7"><h6><a href="#">Galaxy S7</a></h6></div>
    <div class="carousel-pop-item"><img src="img/goods/s8.png" alt="Galaxy S8"><h6><a href="#">Galaxy S8</a></h6></div>
</div>
```

Как мне получить `id` текущего элемента и атрибут `src` текущего изображения в `owl carousel`?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь со следующими ссылками: [Owl Carousel 2 - Get src of current slide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28022311/5275890), [Owl Carousel select current item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26989734/5275890), [Owl Carousel 2 - how to get a current item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33447223/5275890) возможно поможет.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: Думаю, было бы уместно опубликовать ответ, решающий ваш вопрос, чтобы данный вопрос мог принести пользу в дальнейшем.